# CSS Opacity Property

Tags: html, css

Hi i am using CSS Opacity Property for a div tag and it works well but the problem is when I write some text or paste images on that div tag they also become fade. I just need div back color to be fade and not the div content. My code is ...

```
#fade div
{
opacity:0.1;
filter:alpha(opacity=10); /* For IE8 and earlier */
width:750px;
height:150px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

#text in fade div
{
font-weight:bold;
color:#8A2BE2;
}
```

Thankyou !!!

Comment: Can you use CSS3 or do you need to be as widely viewable as possible?

Comment: if you are putting the text/image inside that div the div became parent for that and it contain the property of parent, to batter understand the problem create [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Relevant: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 11):

It's much easier to use `rgba()` or a transparent PNG for the background.

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
rgba(0, 0, 0); //fallback
```

Comment: Thats a good solution. Look up this link to get further information: http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rgba()` property for this:

write like this:

```
#fade div
{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
width:750px;
height:150px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

For IE you can use `IE filter`

```
background: transparent;-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#19000000,endColorstr=#19000000)"; /* IE8 */    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#19000000,endColorstr=#19000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      zoom: 1;
```

You can generate your filter from here http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: yes but shouldn't it be like `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);`

Comment: ie filter not working this way #header {
width:750px;
height:150px;
background-color:#333333;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

<!--[if IE]>
background: transparent;-ms-filter: 
"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#19000000,endColorstr=#19000000)"; /* IE8 */  
filter: 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#19000000,endColorstr=#19000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
zoom: 1;
<![endif]-->

}

Comment: may is the problem with background-color:#333333;. May be you have to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use 1px semi transparent gif and repeat it by x and y. As far as I know it is the most easy way to set semi transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the opacity applies to the child elements as well.What you can do is to segragate your markup.

```
<div id='Div-With-Opacity-set'>
</div>
<div id='Child-Elements-for-the-above-div'>
</div>
```

Align your markup carefully such that the markup resembles what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reset the opacity then?

```
#text in fade div
{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#8A2BE2;
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `opacity` isn't an inherited property anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet without CSS3 is probably to create a div and put another div positioned on top of it, but not nested inside of it. Opacity filters down to ALL elements inside of the element with the opacity set.

If you put a div immediately to the right, and then gave it a margin of -750px;, you could give it an opacity of 1, but the div behind it could have an opacity of 0.1, and this would work fine.

With CSS3 you could do this:

```
#fade 
{
width:750px;
height:150px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
```

and just the background would be 0.1 opacity. The text would still be 1.

What I personally do most often though, is I create a small .png with the transparent background that I want, and then I set that .png as the background of an element. In photoshop I could set the opacity of the white background to 0.1, then save a 50X50 square, and then I've got nearly perfect transparency (no IE6).

Answer (score 0):

something like http://jsfiddle.net/PWM5f/ you need