# Changing opacity level using css property

Tags: css

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #main{
        opacity:1 !important;
        position:absolute;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        top:150px;
        left:300px;
      }
      body{
        opacity:0.3;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div >
  </html>
```

This is the code.I want to apply low opacity to body and a maximum opacity to id Main ,i have tried like this but i did not achieved the desired output.Is there any other way to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the opacity is inherited from the body by the div. Also, it seems that the opacity doesn't work on the body itself at all (which surprises me).

If you just want a semi-transparent background color on body you should use `background-color: rgba(x,x,x,x)`. If you want a transparent image in the body, look at this question:

[CSS Opacity inheritance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070590/css-opacity-inheritance-issue)

Comment: i had same issue.. i agree this answer.. check this http://jsfiddle.net/girishgowdayt/XskGX/

Comment: @BoltClock I put his html/css in a jsfiddle and for some reason it kept giving me a totally opaque background. Not sure if I was doing something wrong too (hence the note that I was surprised). Either way his setup isn't going to work because of inheritance.

Comment: @Stephan Muller: Oh I see what you mean. OK that's going to catch a lot of people off guard - the opacity of `body` does still affect its children, but the background color of `body` is being transferred to `html`, which is opaque, causing `body`'s background color to also appear opaque. This is expected behavior. You can stop that from happening by giving `html` its own background color.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly ? I've test your code, and for me it's good, i've a body without opacity, and a main with opacity.

Comment: He wants it the other way round. I almost gave the same answer but then I read the question again. ('Maximum opacity' = completely opaque, which it's not)

Comment: So why he didn't switch properties ?

Comment: Read again, he uses the right properties for the effect he's trying to accomplish. It just doesn't work that way. He says: "I want to apply low opacity to body and a maximum opacity to id Main", and uses .3 on body (low opacity) and 1 on #Main (max opacity). His logic is right.

Answer (score 0):

the opacity in css is applied to all child elements of the element you applied the opacity to, you could place a div as an overlay or underlay with the opacity you want here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcferrans/kyjjZ/)

```
<body>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
</body>

.overlay {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.3;
}
```