# Changing an image opacity

Tags: html, css

If a section opacity is settled to a certain value, how can I change or disable the opacity of an image inside it? Code demonstration:

CSS

```
#example1{
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

HTML

```
<section id="example1">
    ...
    <img src="a.png">
    ...
</section>
```

So how can I change the a.png opacity?

Comment: Similar concern / answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070590/css-opacity-inheritance-issue (and this was marked a duplicate as well)... just fyi.

Comment: consensus appears to be "you can't"...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613191/why-cant-child-elements-override-the-opacity-of-parent-with-a-greater-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the effect on any of the children that is inside of the parent div.

Let me explain it like this, the `opacity` is being set on the parent container. Then the children are located inside the parent which are nested nice and cozily in there.

So we have this,

--Parent (opacity start)

-----Child

-----Child

--End Parent (opacity end)

Since the children are nested inside of the parent container they will then become transparent due to the parent container being transparent.

As others have stated there are a few ways to go about this.

- One way is using `rgba()` (red, gren, blue, alpha) for transparent background colors
- Make a child inside of the parent positioned `absolute` to be the transparent background like so,

--Parent `<section>`

-----Transparent absolute child

-----Child

-----Child

--End Parent `</section>`

My last example, a fun one, to explain this is with the use of Harry Potter.

In the books Harry receives a clock of invisibility. With this cloak, once worn, can make him invisible! This is exactly like your example except you can control the transparency of the object!

Here we go,

--Cloak (parent)

-----Harry Potter (Child)

--End Cloak (end parent)

Since he is inside of his cloak he is therefor invisible, just like your child elements.

Pertaining to the OP's question,

> Okay remove the opacity on the #mainWrapper now, where ever you are
>   using this color, #29630E, replace it with, rgba(41, 99, 14, 0.9), and
>   you will not have everything being transparent. What you are doing,
>   without realizing, is making everything on that page transparent. The
>   text, color, images, everything transparent. With the use of rgba you
>   will only be making the background color transparent.

Comment: I tried the rgba solution but it doesn't work as I mentioned in the answer below, you have any idea why?

Comment: Okay well the next thing I can ask is, What are you trying to make transparent?

Comment: I want to make a section transparent, inside it I want to have a picture which is not transparent. I tried to add the rgba peoperty to the image but it doesn't working as I said in the answer below.

Comment: Okay well one, `rgba` is for color not images and second, what section are you trying to make transparent? some text on top of the image?

Comment: The section that wraps the site is transparent since it looks nice with the body background. This part is working fine but the only thing left to do is change somehow the image opacity.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: I'll provide a link to the page with the picture: http://www.spikes.co.il/index.php?a=product&item=2 the site is in hebrew so don't really try to understand it xD

Comment: lol yeah I won't even try to read that, okay remove the opacity on the `#mainWrapper` now where ever you are using this color, #29630E, replace it with, `rgba(41, 99, 14, 0.9)`, and you will not have everything being transparent. What you are doing, without realizing, is making everything on that page transparent. The text, color, images, everything transparent. With the use of `rgba` you will only be making the background color transparent.

Comment: Thanks for your effort!! That's so nice to have people like you :)

Comment: And sorry for beeing annoying, changing the text opacity now would be a problem or not?

Comment: Your not being annoying at all and you are so welcome! If you want some text to be transparent then you would simply do something like this, `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);`. That is #000(black) with a 40% opacity on it,

Comment: I mean the text is now transparent, how can I disable the transparent?

Comment: Hmm I just checked the site and it doesn't seem to be transparent.

Comment: If I will change the opacity to 0.5 you will see that, but you're right you can't even notice. Once again thank you and have a good day! :)

Comment: No problem and best of luck in your design!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rgba() property](http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/) like  this:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
```

Something like this:

```
#example1{
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

Comment: I'm changing the opacity value from 0.8 to 1, but it stays the same.

Comment: @ImriPersiado:- Are you using the rgba property?

Comment: <img src="example.png" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);">

Comment: @ImriPersiado:- Can you try to put this in your CSS instead of your HTML?

Comment: Change it to <img class="non_opacity" ...> css: .non_opacity{background: rgb(0, 0, 0);background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);} and it doesn't work..

Comment: @ImriPersiado:- You dont need this background: rgb(0, 0, 0); Its for the fallback. Just try this: background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

Comment: Now its: .non_opacity
{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
} and it's still not working =\

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Maybe because of what the guy above said: "if the section is already set opacity, you can't reset the opacity of its child"

Answer (score 0):

if the section is already set opacity, you can't reset the opacity of its child, but you can do like this, set imitation of opacity via pseude-element, something like this

```
section{
position:relative;
}

section:before{
 content:'';
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

then play with the opacity of the image as you want

Comment: The child is the section:before? So the image will be reffered to the section:before?

Comment: No child is the image, :before just overlay for the section - the imitation of the opacity

In fact :before also children of the section but used for imitation

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the sections opacity, change the opacity of the children that are not an img. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/taDFs/)

```
section > *:not(img) {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```