# Turning off opacity on centered div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a box that appears in the center of a website. To do that I dynamically (js) create two elements - overlay that covers whole page and has 0.5 opacity to show some website, and a box that should have no opacity.

The problem is that both the overlay and the box are a bit transparent.

```
this.createOverlay = function () {
            handler = document.createElement('div');
            handler.style.display = 'hidden';
            handler.style.width = '100%';
            handler.style.height = '100%';
            handler.style.top = 0;
            handler.style.left = 0;
            handler.style.position = 'absolute';
            handler.style.background = 'black';
            handler.style.color = "#aaaaaa";
            handler.style.opacity = "0.5";
            handler.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = 5)";
            return this;
        };
        this.createCenteredBox = function (width, height, url) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);

            handler = document.createElement('a');
            handler.href = data.product_feed_deep_link;
            handler.target = "_blank";
            handler.style.display = "block";
            handler.style.width = width + "px";
            handler.style.height = height + "px";
            handler.style.position = "absolute";
            handler.style.color = "black";
            handler.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
            handler.style.opacity = "1";
            handler.style.top = "50%";
            handler.style.left = "50%";
            handler.style.marginTop = "-" + height / 2 + "px";
            handler.style.marginLeft = "-" + width / 2 + "px";
            handler.style.padding = "0 10px 10px 10px";
            handler.style.borderRadius = "4px";
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            handler.appendChild(div);
            return this;
        };
```

This is the code, I can't turn off box'es opacity no matter if I set opacity to 1 on it, or opacity filter, or whatever.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Opacity isn't inherited ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp)), however, all elements that reside inside (descendants) of that elements that the opacity property is applied to will be effected.

The best way to get around this is to use `rgba`.

```
handler.style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)";  // RGB 0,0,0 is #000 (black).
//handler.style.opacity = "0.5";
//handler.style.filter = "alpha(opacity = 5)";
```

See [2nd and 3rd answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070590/css-opacity-inheritance-issue) as well