# How to avoid inheriting opacity property in CSS?

Tags: css, opacity

I have a `div` element to which I set `opacity: 0.7;` in the CSS file because I would like the text inside it to be opaque. I display some images inside this `div`, but the images appear with the inherited opacity property. The result are opaque images.

Is it possible to give a CSS property to the images not to inherit the opacity of the `div` that contains them? If not, how can I avoid having the images opaque?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by setting `opacity`? Can it be done with `background-color` and `rgba`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Opacity Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237886/css-opacity-property)

Comment: I would like to have the text inside the div opaque. Aaand no. No possible duplicate, sorry.

Comment: Opaque means "not transparent or translucent". I think you mean you want the text to be semi-transparent. Use `color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `opacity` to allow the *text* to have partial transparency, then simply set the `color` of the element:

```
#elemId {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

This lets you avoid adjusting the `opacity` property, and *should* work in all browsers that support the `opacity` property, too.

Comment: Sadly this is not working. If I remove the `opacity: 0.7;` line and put `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);` the text turns to black, and it's not semi-transparent/opaque as I would like to have it. I'm running on the latest version of Chrome so I don't think it's a browser problem...

Comment: I don't know why, but I tested and the text is opaque, but not as much as I want it to be. I modified your suggestion as so: `color: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);` and it seems to work. I have no idea why, but in this way I can achieve something similar to what I had with `opacity: 0.7`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Only way is with positioning. Here is a great article from CSS Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/non-transparent-elements-inside-transparent-elements/

Use `position: relative;` and a top value to make elements over one another.

If you are just trying to make a background transparent then you can use the `rgba()` value in your background.

**Edit:**

Here is a crazy idea. You could use PHP GD to render a image with a gray backround(making transparent) with white text that you want to display in the correct position. Then use a `mask-box-image` or `mask-image` CSS property and set it to the rendered image.

If of course your content is not dynamic then you could make the image in Photoshop/whatever program.

Anti-aliasing would not be the same from the browser to the GD render but is the best hack if you do not want to use positioning.

Comment: I would prefer not to modify the HTML this way. I'm searching for a CSS solution, but thanks.

Comment: @Masiar Added solution involving CSS and a some PHP

Comment: Thanks, it's an interesting solution, and I like it because it's crazy, but I'll go with the `color: ` solution! Anyways +1 =)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in your css

z-index:111

it works.