# How to make two divs with transparency

Tags: css, html, transparency, z-index, opacity

I need to make div, which will have for example opacity:0.5, an inside of this will be another div, which won´t be transparent. I can´t figure this out. Even if I set z-index of inner div higher than the outter div, it´s still everything transparent. Now I got it like this:

```
<div id="outter" style="opacity:0.5; z-index:-1">
    <div id="inner" style="opacity:1; z-index:1">
        <img src="someImg.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<div id="outter" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);">
    <div id="inner" style="opacity:1; z-index:1">
        <img src="Your image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Opacity inheritance is quite finicky. You could try hack your way around it, or use `rgba()` on `#outer` (remove opacity and z-index)

Like:

```css
#outter { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
```

[Similar quesition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237886/css-opacity-property)

Answer (score 0):

`opacity` is inherited by all children, so it's not so useful in this scenario. A better option is to use `rgba` colors. So, for example, you could set the colors of the outer div to

```
.outer {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
```

... and so on.

The only other option—if you are determined to stick with `opacity`—is to place the inner div outside of the container and reposition it over the top of the `.outer` div. (You would need to wrap them both in another container with `position: relative` to do that, and then position the inner div absolutely in relation to it.)